# Python: How to ignore non-letter characters and treat all alphabetic characters as lower case?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in Python that checks if the inputted string is in alphabetical order (abcdearian). The program needs to ignore non-letter characters and treat capital letters as lowercase letters. For example...
abCde is abcdearian and eff!ort is abcdearian.
Right now the program does not ignore non-letter characters, but it does treat capital letters as lowercase letters. However, I want the program to print the original input, and not the converted one. So abCde should show up as abCde (not abcde) when it is printed. Thanks for the help!

```
def isabcde(s):
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] > s[i+1]:
            return print(s, "is not abcdearian")
    return print(s,  "is abcdearian")


while True:
    try:
        s = input("The string? ").lower()
    except EOFError:
        break
    except TypeError:
        break
    isabcde(s)
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, make a list with alphabet and check if the character of string is not in that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try this:

```
def isabcde(s):
    filtered = [i for i in s.lower() if i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz']
    for i in range(len(filtered) - 1):
        if filtered[i] > filtered[i+1]:
            return print(s, "is not abcdearian")
    return print(s,  "is abcdearian")

while True:
    try:
        s = input("The string? ")
    except EOFError:
        break
    except TypeError:
        break
    isabcde(s)
```

and if you are ambitious, you may try to replace:

```
    for i in range(len(filtered) - 1):
        if filtered[i] > filtered[i+1]:
```

with:

```
    if all([i[0] < i[1] for i in zip(filtered,filtered[1:]) :
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `string.lower()` outside of the function, you could do it inside, like so:

```
def isabcde(s):
    original = s
    s = s.lower()
    for i in range(len(s) - 1):
        if s[i] > s[i+1]:
            print(original, "is not abcdearian")
            return
    print(original,  "is abcdearian")

while True:
    try:
        s = input("The string? ")
    except EOFError:
        break
    except TypeError:
        break
    isabcde(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
def is_abcdearian(s):
    import re
    s = s.lower()
    s = re.sub('[^a-z]', '', s)
    return s == ''.join(sorted(s))
```